# WPF MenuItem usability by mouse

Tags: wpf, user-interface, menuitem, usability, wpf-style

WPF `MenuItem` is only selected when user hovers mouse **exactly over the text** of `MenuItem`.
If user clicks now then menu will be expanded, good:
[image]

This does not happen when mouse is **not over the text**.
If user clicks in this situation then nothing happens (you can see background of `MenuItem` is darkened, i.e. mouse is not over the element):
[image]

This is quite incovenient, uses complained, I even set bold font to increase area where user clicks succeed to open submenu.
Code is very simple:

```
<MenuItem x:Name="MainMenuItem" Header="Menu" ToolTipService.HasDropShadow="True" 
                  Foreground="{StaticResource BasicBritnessForeground}" FontWeight="Bold">
```

How to fix this?

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem with a plain ``MenuItem`` but it expands its sub items even if click its margins. It might be related to your ``Style``. Can post code around your ``Style``?

Comment: You should post a minimal reproduction. What you posted is not the cause.